# Certifcate: Unknown, Profile: None in xcode 10.1 archive

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ad-hoc-distribution, xcode10.1

[image]
I tried to create an ad hoc build to test push notification in production certificate. While creating ipa file, I cannot install it via iTunes and had to load ipa using xcode. I'm using Houston to test it in command line, it prompts that push notification is sent but notification is not received.

Furthermore, I tried making a testflight build. Build is created and uploaded successfully but installed app has same problem i.e. push notification is not received. I searched this problem online and came across this thread https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110438 but no conclusive answer is given there. Is anyone facing the same problem? Has anybody found a solution?

Comment: Do you have all needed certificates created?? Also is it okay if you are in Debug mode??

Comment: Yes, I've all the certificates. It works fine in debug mode. I've not tried creating development build from archive but running app directly to device works perfectly.

Comment: Any resolution on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the build and restart XCode and try to re login the apple id in your XCode account preferences.

[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/lhdd5n)

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue: Apps validate and distribute fine, so I guess this is just a display issue introduced by XCode 10.1.
or you can downgrade Xcode To 10.0 and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not just a display issue!** While apple may allow you to publish these builds, some features like Push notifications require the correct profile. Publishing a build created like this (without a correct profile) has broken push for several apps (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110438).

There are 2 solutions I've found:

- select "Manually manage signing" in the "Distribute App" wizard, and select a valid profile in the next step. **However this sometimes still shows "Profile: none" so be careful to double check.**
- download xCode 10 (not 10.1) from developer center, and use it for publishing.

Hopefully xcode 10.1+ are fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I elected manual management of signing during the Validation and Distribution processes, downloading the appropriate provisioning profile (which was absent), then followed the steps from the following link to confirm that my entitlements were as expected.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1798/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this Apple Developer Forum [post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/338402#338402) this is fixed in Xcode 10.2.  I upgraded to 10.2 and can confirm that it is fixed.